# Drawing a circle (with sectors) using HTML, CSS, or jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, geometry

I want to draw a circle with sectors on it without using external images like the image below:

[image: Circle]

I'd prefer using HTML, CSS, or jQuery, but if they don't work, then any other language will do.

Comment: holy hell, that is an image? almost escaped my eyes.

Comment: @deostroll: http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24737168/1811992

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/)?

From the web site:

> Raphaël is a small JavaScript library
>   that should simplify your work with
>   vector graphics on the web. If you
>   want to create your own specific chart
>   or image crop and rotate widget, for
>   example, you can achieve it simply and
>   easily with this library.
>
> ...
>
> Raphaël currently supports Firefox
>   3.0+, Safari 3.0+, Chrome 5.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+.

Answer (score 7):

Coming late to the party, but if you can get away with not supporting IE < 9 you can do it in pure CSS.
[image]

```
<div id="center">
  <div id="tl"></div>
  <div id="tr"></div>
  <div id="bl"></div>
  <div id="br"></div>
</div>

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius:  100px;
}

#center {
  position: relative; 
  margin: 100px 0 0 100px; 
  border: solid #fff 1px; 
}

#tl, #tr, #bl, #br {
  position: absolute;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#tl {
  border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
}

#tr {
  border-radius: 0 100px 0 0;
  top: -50px;
  left: 26px;
}

#bl {
  border-radius:  0 0 0 100px;
  top: 26px;
  left: -50px;
}

#br {
  border-radius: 0  0 100px 0;
  top: 26px;
  left: 26px;
}
```

See the code in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/nchtG/

If you need to support IE in versions less than 9, as Andrew already mentioned, Raphaël is your best option.

Comment: Ya man you came late, Very simple css code. But i am not understanding that css can u explain me. Thank you

Comment: Thats pretty awesome that u drew that with just css I would never have thought it possible...

Comment: For the record: this works on IE 11, and *should* work on IE 9 & 10.

Comment: @Niek thanks for the notice, updated the answer. IE 9 didn't exist when I answered this (I think!).

Answer (score 1):

See [this article for CSS Shapes](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Obviously only good browsers would support this, but here's how I'd go about doing it --

- Have a container element that is position:relative.
- Inside of that, have an element that, based on the article above, is a circle.
- After that (but on-top of the circle element using z-index), have 2 absolutely positioned elements that have use rgba and are transparent fill color, but have white borders to make up the Cross-section
- On top of that, have a final circle with a highest z-index, that makes the central circle

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the [HTML5 Canvas](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_canvas.htm).

HTML5 is currently in development, so you will need to use an [external library](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) (which is quite easy to setup) if you wish to include support for IE by stubborn ol' Microsoft:

> The latest versions of Firefox,
>   Safari, Chrome and Opera all support
>   for HTML5 Canvas but IE8 does not
>   support canvas natively.
>
> You can use [ExplorerCanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) to
>   have canvas support through Internet
>   Explorer. You just need to include
>   this javascript as follows:
>
> ```
> <!--[if IE]><script src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
> ```

Answer (score 0):

using [HTML canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes).

but would not work on IE though...

Comment: Just to point it out - the user said using CSS or jQuery, not HTML canvas...

@Reigel - My apologies I overlooked that.

Comment: @Connor - title says, "How can i draw a circle with sectors on it using **html**, css or jquery"