# How can I make a circular sector using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to make a circular sector using CSS. The sectors will form a complete circle. How can I make it using CSS?

I found a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/nchtG/), but it makes a quarter circular sector. I want to make six circular sectors that make a complete circle. How can I make it?

Note: I am not good at drawing, but here's a sample of what I want...

[image: circle devided in sectors]

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
#center {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px 0 0 100px;
  border: solid #fff 1px;
}
#tl,#tr,#bl,#br {
  position: absolute;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  z-index: -1;
}
#tl {
  border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
}
#tr {
  border-radius: 0 100px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 100px 0 0;
  top: -50px;
  left: 26px;
}
#bl {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 100px;
  top: 26px;
  left: -50px;
}
#br {
  border-radius: 0 0 100px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 100px 0;
  top: 26px;
  left: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div id="center">
  <div id="tl"></div>
  <div id="tr"></div>
  <div id="bl"></div>
  <div id="br"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The link to the sample page doesn't exist. (404)

Comment: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200805/css_homer_animated.html 

or if you think js is also okay here it is: 
http://www.walterzorn.de/en/jsgraphics/jsgraphics_e.htm

Comment: or this: 
http://www.designdetector.com/tips/3DBorderDemo2.html

Comment: but this shape is what you want exactly:
http://www.gabri.me/demo/Coffee%20with%20CSS3%20Gradients/

Comment: this is the css of this coffee cup with circle edges... 
http://pastebin.de/27953

hope this is enough :))

Comment: @doniyor, It's not the shape I want!  I don't want circle, I want circular sectors.

Comment: +1 for your painting skills

Comment: @doniyor - The JS solution you suggested creates hundreds of `1px` `div`s, it's not the best solution in my opinion (e.g. `:hover` won't work). @PalAla - is this what you are looking for? http://i.imgur.com/zw8VQ.png

Comment: oh yeah, i thought, PalAla can derive some ideas/codes from those examples.. but your one is of course the thing what PalAla is after, i guess...

Comment: That would be a good use-case for SVG.

Answer (score 15):

I have finished the menu: [**Circular menu v6 - jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LMPcB/1/).

There is no JavaScript involved in this menu. It's done in pure CSS!

**Here is the code:**

```css
#menu {
  background: #aaa;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
}

#center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 70px;
  top: 70px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #eee;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #eee, #aaa);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #aaa);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#eee), to(#aaa));
  border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
}

#center a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.item {
  background: #aaa;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transition: background .5s;
  -moz-transition: background .5s;
  -webkit-transition: background .5s;
  -o-transition: background .5s;
  -ms-transition: background .5s;
}

.item:hover {
  background: #eee
}

.item1 {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.item2 {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
}

.item3 {
  z-index: 3;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.item4 {
  z-index: 4;
  transform: rotate(240deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(240deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg);
}

.item5 {
  z-index: 5;
  transform: rotate(300deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(300deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
}

.item6 {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

#wrapper6 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.item1 .content {
  left: -10px;
  top: 15px;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.item2 .content {
  left: -11px;
  top: 16px;
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-120deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-120deg);
}

.item3 .content {
  left: -7px;
  top: 12px;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.item4 .content {
  left: -5px;
  top: 18px;
  transform: rotate(-240deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-240deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-240deg);
}

.item5 .content {
  left: -10px;
  top: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-300deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-300deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-300deg);
}

.item6 .content {
  left: 20px;
  top: -10px;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.content,
.content a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
}

.content a {
  line-height: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #eee;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 5px #fff
}

.display-target {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
}

.display-target:target {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fade-in 1s;
  -moz-animation: fade-in 1s;
  -webkit-animation: fade-in 1s;
  -o-animation: fade-in 1s;
  -ms-animation: fade-in 1s;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div class="item1 item">
    <div class="content"><a href="#one">one</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item2 item">
    <div class="content"><a href="#two">two</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item3 item">
    <div class="content"><a href="#three">three</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item4 item">
    <div class="content"><a href="#four">four</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item5 item">
    <div class="content"><a href="#five">five</a></div>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper6">
    <div class="item6 item">
      <div class="content"><a href="#six">six</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="center">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="one" class="display-target">Welcome!
  <br />This changing effect is done by ...</div>
<div id="two" class="display-target">... having <code>&lt;div&gt;</code>s with <code>id</code>s ... </div>
<div id="three" class="display-target">... that have the style <code>display: none</code> and the style
  <pre style="text-align: left">:target {
    display: block;
}</pre>so that these messages appear when there is a hash tag like <code>#three</code> (look at the address bar!)</div>
<div id="four" class="display-target">Look at the source of this page ...</div>
<div id="five" class="display-target">... to see how the circular menu works.</div>
<div id="six" class="display-target">By Shaquin Trifonoff</div>
<p><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/1421049/shaquin-trifonoff" title="My profile on Stack Overflow">By Shaquin Trifonoff</a></p>
```

Comment: **+1** I like that this Answer, done in CSS, includes fade animations. Cheers!

Comment: @arttronics Thanks for putting it on jsFiddle! I forgot!

Comment: @arttronics - I've linked to a Fiddle (in an edit) with links on the menu (using `:target`), that is how it was on my website.

Comment: The fiddle seems to be missing a `border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;` on the `.item` class, otherwise the circumfrance isn't circular in chrome.

Comment: @Jeemusu - Thanks for that, it looks like a Chrome-only bug (it doesn't listen to `overflow: hidden` on `#menu` and works fine on Firefox), I have made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LMPcB/4/) with `border-radius` and `-webkit-border-radius`, because I don't know how old the bug is. (It's probably because of `transform`, Firefox has a `z-index` bug with `transform` rather than an `overflow` bug).

Answer (score 5):

### Simple circle seperated in 6 sectors

Using borders on pseudo elements to make the triangles:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/hX7nZ/)**

output:

[image: CSS circle seperated in 6 sectors]

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle:before,
.circle:after,
.circle > div:before,
.circle > div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.circle:before {
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border-top: 300px solid transparent;
  border-right: 150px solid gold;
}

.circle:after {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-right: 150px solid gold;
  border-bottom: 300px solid transparent;
}

.sector1:before {
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border-top: 300px solid transparent;
  border-left: 150px solid gold;
}

.sector1:after {
  bottom: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-top: 300px solid gold;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
}

.sector2:before {
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-bottom: 300px solid transparent;
  border-left: 150px solid gold;
}

.sector2:after {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 300px solid gold;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
}

.round-middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 96px;
  left: 96px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="sector1"></div>
  <div class="sector2"></div>
  <div class="round-middle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using `-moz-transform`, try this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raymondralibi/nchtG/751/)**. Actually, we don't need `.sec1.sec_` to `.sec4.sec_`. And then `.sec5.sec_` is `.sec6`

```css
#container {
  margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
  position: relative;
}

#center {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0px;
  border: solid #fff 1px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.outer_sec {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 25px;
}

.sec {
  position: absolute;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sec1.sec {
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #cc1;
}

.sec2.sec {
  -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #cb2;
}

.sec3.sec {
  -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: #ca3;
}

.sec4.sec {
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  z-index: 4;
  background-color: #c94;
}

.sec5.sec {
  -moz-transform: rotate(240deg);
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #c85;
}

.sec6.sec {
  -moz-transform: rotate(300deg);
  z-index: 6;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 50px;
  background-color: #c76;
  top: -74px;
}

.sec:hover {
  background-color: #06c;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="sec1 sec"></div>
  <div class="sec2 sec"></div>
  <div class="sec3 sec"></div>
  <div class="sec4 sec"></div>
  <div class="sec5 sec"></div>
  <div class="outer_sec">
    <div class="sec6 sec"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="center"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've updated the [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raymondralibi/nchtG/749/). too bad, `:hover` still not working.

Comment: It's quarter, the shape i need is 1/6, the same as image here http://i.imgur.com/zw8VQ.png

Comment: no, it's not quarter. maybe you can't see because it don't have outlines. maybe you have to see it using FF. for fast reply, it's only use -moz-transform (not include -webkit or -o), i've only tested it with FF. it's 1/6, not quarter.

Comment: i've figured it out, the problem is its z-index. i've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raymondralibi/nchtG/751/) again.

Comment: It's too bad that this example doesn't allow text to be presented inside each sector, severely limiting it's use.

Comment: It surely allows text. Put a `div` inside each sector and set the position with css. this example doesn't use text 'cause we don't know what the question want, e.g. alignment, orientation, size, etc.

Comment: @raymondralibi, that's a fair statement. But considering the other answer has `text` in it (to allow *text-links* or *labels* for example), the bar has been raised ***to a higher standard***. To be sure, I did upvote you yesterday. Cheers!