# Covering an image using a div element

Tags: html, css

#### My Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/yjw46/2/

#### My Goal

I have this beautiful wheel of colors as a PNG. (I also have it as an SVG). When one of the colors is clicked, I want the WHOLE circle to change to that color. For example, if red is clicked, I want the whole wheel to turn red instead of colorful.

#### How I Intended to do it

I wanted to have a transparent (in the Fiddle it's semi-transparent, for debugging purposes) div in the shape of a circle (using `border-radius`) that will be DIRECTLY ON my color-wheel-image. When a color is pressed, I planned for the div to stop being tranparent, and (in a beautiful transition) turn to that color, making it look like the whole wheel has changed color.

#### Problem

I cannot get the div to cover the image.

#### So

I'd be glad to hear either why my technique didn't work, or a better technique, if you have one.

Comment: How did you intend to detect witch color is clicked?

Comment: Using a `<map>`, that I haven't put in the Fiddle

Comment: this might be usefull for your aim [seperate circle into sectors](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24737168/1811992)

Comment: To get the div on the image just set it to absolute. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/yjw46/8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You was very close, simply chanage `position: relative;` to `position: absolute;` (on the `div` you want to have over the image) to fix the problem.

Now remember we need to have the parent as `position: relative;` or the absolute positioned `div` will not sit in the parent. You have already set this so its good to go.

Find more on `position: absolute;` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/yjw46/8/)

```
#circleCover {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 150px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

---

Here is a little demo to show what will happen without the `relative` position being set on the parent with the child having `absolute`.

[Demo Without Relative](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/StXkp/)

So you can see that the child is not staying within the parent.

And here is the parent with relative position.

[Demo With Relative](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/StXkp/1/)

As here the child does stay within the parent. This should help you understand why that is needed for the task you are trying to accomplish. Any questions please do just leave a comment and I will get back to you.

Comment: This is a neat answer, and well explained.

Comment: Glad you made peace :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="circleWrap">
  <img src="http://y.emuze.co/circle.png" id="colorCircle"/>
  <div id="circleCover" >
  </div>
</div>
```

I have kept Your div one above the other

```
#colorCircle {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px; left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    top:0px;
}

#circleWrap {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#circleCover {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    top: -302px; left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 150px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/yjw46/7/

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS slightly.

```
#circleCover {
   top:-304px; 
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yjw46/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add **position:absolute** in #colorCircle

```
#colorCircle {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px; left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Ruddy, Oh I didn't see your answer, sorry about that. Besides it's not a copied version. Go get the price then.